# Is there a way to enable/disable Intellij IdeaVim plugin using keyboard shortcut?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, ideavim

I am using IdeaVim in Intellij as I can't really get over modular editing. But there are times when I just want it completely disabled (like when a coworker shows me something on my computer).

I know it can be disabled through the plugin manager by unchecking the enabled box, but this does not really cut it for me in many cases as it is too slow and disruptive for quick.

What would be nice to have is to make some keyboard shortcut to disable and enable the plugin so that I can easily switch between the modes. Is there a way to do this so that I don't have to restart Intellij for the changes to apply?

(Keeping vim in insert mode would not work in my case as it jumps to command mode at times for no reason)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Vim plugin can be disabled via `Tools | Vim`. There was an assigned shortcut, but it conflicted with some of IDE shortcuts and it was removed. You can assign your own shortcut using regular IDE mapping.

[image]

Comment: As of July 2022, the shortcut can only "Enable" the Vim emulation mode, but not disable or toggle it. Kind of a deal breaker to me :(

Comment: @Vym can you please file an issue here and attach the log (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files)? This shortcut should work fine. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/VIM

Comment: As of 2023, the shortcut can toggle enable/disable IdeaVIM.

Answer (score 2):

As of now IdeaVim has a toggle in the Tools menu.

[screenshot of tools menu showing Vim item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBffD.png)